# Pass one row from grid view to another grid view asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am wondering of how to pass data, that's one row from Grid View1 to Grid View2 in the same Web form!I created two tables, the first one contains four columns and contains records: Id, name, address and age.
I also created the second form which also contains four columns: Id, name, address and age, but left empty for purpose of transmitting data from the first table.
I wonder if it is possible if to select one row from Grid view1 and then click a button which enables to pass that selected row to Grid View2 !? One row each a time added after hitting the send button to the second grid view and guarantees that data added to the second table!

Any ideas of how to do that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't think of it as "passing a row from one GridView to another" Instead, think of it as you're manipulating the underlying data so that the row no longer shows up in the result set of one of them, and it'll show up in the other. Then you just rebind the GridViews. By the way, you should post your existing code so that whoever answers doesn't have to write it from scratch.

Comment: I have only thoughts of making it and just wanted to know others' views.

Comment: Since it's just conceptual, did my comment give you enough information to proceed on your own?

Comment: No yet, but you pointed out to a good issue which is data is no longer would be in the first grid view and would show up in the other! would it be stored in the second table?

Comment: Yes. In C# code, select the data for that row into some model object to use as temporary storage for that row. Then delete the data from table #1, then insert it into table #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you an overview of some steps you might want to take

I assume you use a `DataSet` or a `DataTable` where your records are stored in.

- use the eventHandler of the gridview, like `CellClick`, most of them have a `e.RowIndex` value, which you can use to get the index of the row that is selected

Like this:

```
    private void dg1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            selectedIndex = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

- use that index to get the `id` from that record, so you know what data you are talking about

like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[selectedIndex][0]);
```

then just find the row by id or use the knowledge above to combine this

```
DataRow row = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Find(Id);
dg2.Rows.Add(row);
```

it's better to use datasets and give the datagridview a datasource to that dataset, not sure what your intentions are

- you could also get the `id` from the row you selected, based on that you call another sqlCommand to get that current row, a good way if you have more data you want to load from the database that rely on that `id`